# Brezis' proposition 7.2: how does the writing $A\left(A_\lambda v\right)$ make sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, hilbert-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

Let $H$ together with an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ be a real Hilbert space. Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator.

> **Definition.** Let $A: D(A) \subset H \to H$ be a maximal monotone (unbounded linear) operator. For every $\lambda>0$, set
> $$
> J_\lambda=(I+\lambda A)^{-1} \quad \text { and } \quad A_\lambda=\frac{1}{\lambda}\left(I-J_\lambda\right) ;
> $$
> $J_\lambda$ is called the *resolvent* of $A$, and $A_\lambda$ is the *Yosida approximation* (or *regularization*) of $A$. Keep in mind that $\left\|J_\lambda\right\|_{\mathcal{L}(H)} \leq 1$.

I'm reading a proposition in Brezis' *Funtional Analysis*

> **Proposition 7.2.** Let A be a maximal monotone operator. Then
>
> - (a1) $A_\lambda v = A (J_\lambda v)$ for all $v \in H$ and for all $\lambda>0$,
> - (a2) $A_\lambda v = J_\lambda (A v)$ for all $v \in D(A)$ and for all $\lambda>0$.

The proof is given as follows.

> (a1) can be written as $v=\left(J_\lambda v\right)+\lambda A\left(J_\lambda v\right)$, which is just the definition of $J_\lambda v$.
>
> (a2) By (a1), we have
> $$
> A_\lambda v+A\left(v-J_\lambda v\right)=A v,
> $$
> i.e.,
> $$
> A_\lambda v+\lambda A\left(A_\lambda v\right)=A v,
> $$
> which means that $A_\lambda v=(I+\lambda A)^{-1} A v$.

Let $R(A_\lambda)$ be the range of $A_\lambda$. Could you please explain how $R(A_\lambda) \subset D(A)$ so that the writing $A\left(A_\lambda v\right)$ makes sense?

Comment: Your interpretation of the text is incorrect.  It only claims that if $v\in D(A)$ then $A_\lambda v\in D(A)$.  This is true, because $(I+\lambda A)$ maps $D(A)$ onto $H$, so $J_\lambda$ maps $H$ onto $D(A)$, and if $v\in D(A)$ then both $v$ and $J_\lambda v$ are in $D(A)$, so $A_\lambda v\in D(A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JohnDoe mentioned in a comment, I interpreted the text incorrectly. It's not necessarily true that $R(A_\lambda) \subset D(A)$. However, it's true that the image of $D(A)$ through $A_\lambda$ is a subspace of $D(A)$, i.e.,
$$
A_\lambda v \in D(A)
\quad \forall v \in D(A).
$$